# File in a list and then split every term in the list, python

Tags: python, list, split, words

I have a file with words like:

```
IA45,TA43,WB58,AB71 ... etc
```

and I want to convert this words in a list, like:

```
["IA45","TA43","WB58","AB71" .....]
```

Then,i want to use this list to take words one by one and split and take the first letter, the second letter and the number as separated variables.
I have:

```
with open("IRL.txt", "r") as f:
    resid_list = [x.split(',') for x in f.readlines()]
    for r in resid_list:
        chain = list(r)[1]
        print chain
        res = list(r)[0]
        print res
        num = list(r)[2:]
        num1 = "".join(num)
        res_num = res+num1
        print res_num+" "+chain
```

The problem is in the for loop. When i print "chain" it only gave me the second word, and nothing else ---> TA43

But i want to print --- A

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like the following:

```
with open("IRL.txt", "r") as f:
    resid_list = [x for line in f.readlines() for x in line.split(',')]
    for r in resid_list:
        first = r[0]
        second = r[1]
        num = r[2:]
        # do something with those variables
```

In your current version `resid_list` is a list of lists, but I think you want a flat list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a very simple solution. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change `for r in resid_list` into `for r in resid_list[0]`

Since you are using list comprehension, your parameter looks like this:

```
In [9]: resid_list
Out[9]: [['IA45', 'TA43', 'WB58', 'AB71']]
```

i.e. a list of lists

```
In [10]: resid_list[0]
Out[10]: ['IA45', 'TA43', 'WB58', 'AB71']
```

gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Could use `re.findall` and take the first match with a generator expression

```
import re

line = 'IA45,TA43,WB58,AB71'
for fst, snd, nums in (re.findall('(.)(.)(\d+)', el)[0] for el in line.split(',')):
    print fst, snd, nums

I A 45
T A 43
W B 58
A B 71
```

Depending on how well formatted/predictable your line is, you may even be able to get away with just:

```
for fst, snd, nums in re.findall('(.)(.)(\d+)', line):
    print fst, snd, nums
```